# Finding if the element exist in a given range

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. And I have to find the number of elements required by array `C` to fit into a specific length.

```
Length = B[i]-A[i]
```

For example:

```
A[0] = 1    B[0] = 4
A[1] = 4    B[1] = 5
A[2] = 5    B[2] = 9
A[3] = 8    B[3] = 10
and 
C[0] = 4
C[1] = 6
C[2] = 7
C[3] = 10
C[4] = 2
```

Answer would be `4`.

Explanation:

```
C[0] is falling in the range of (A[0],B[0]) and (A[1],B[1])
C[1] is falling in the range of (A[2],B[2]) 
C[2] is of no use
C[3] is falling in the range of (A[3],B[3])
so the total is 4
```

My approaches:
**Traditional approach**: Simple looping every element of `C` in array `A` and if find in the range set the value of `A[i]` and `B[i]` to minus infinity or remove them(for Arraylist).

- **Time complexity** is an issue so not a good approach.

**HashTable**: Storing the value in hash table as `A[i]` as key and `B[i]` as value. Then finding the element for a given `C[i]` and removing the key. I think it is not a good approach 
Please provide me a efficient algorithm for this.

Comment: Can you use a same range several times ?

Comment: @Dici would you please explain i am not getting you

Comment: for example, if C[1] was 3, could you use it even if range (A[0],B[0]) has already been used for C[0] ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: @Dici no ,if element exist in a range , so it is marked as visited so you can remove A[0],B[0] as it is already used by C[0]

Comment: If length = b[i] - a[1], then why is the answer 4? Aren't you really just counting the number of times elements in C fall into unique A,B ranges, eliminating an A,B range if an element in C falls into it, and then incrementing a counter for every eliminated range?

Comment: @0O0O0O0 ya , my mistake

Comment: Just to clarify: is the answer 4 because you used 4 elements from A and B, or because you needed 4 elements from C (even though you didn't use C[2])?

Comment: Also, is the order of the elements important? It looks like A is already in ascending order but is that intentional? What about C? If we sort it then we can get the answer faster but maybe that wouldn't be the right answer (eg we would use C[4] first because it would be moved to C[0])

Comment: @Constantinos A is ascending order and we can't sort C , if we sort it we will getting the wrong answwer , and answer is 4 because we use 4 element from C(includng non used because we have to go by order) to cover all elements from A

Comment: Is this homework ('the wrong answer')? Your description of the problem is very confusing and I suspect that this confusion is extending to your code. You don't 'use 4 elements from C to cover all elements from A'. There are elements in A that are not in any range covered by C, like 1. Why can't you sort C? Why does it give you the wrong answer?

Comment: Is the integer range limited to the left (i.e., is there an integer, for example 0, that is guaranteed to be the lowest)? Can you make assumptions on the number (count), range and granularity of the integers? (If both yes, I may add an answer...)

Comment: yes @JoSo you can , and 0 is lowest element can be possiable

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, and `C` "static" (like, fixed beforehand) or must "dynamic" queries be possible?

Comment: It would really help making the question understandable if you would distinguish concepts and implementation. An array is something that has *order*. In your case the intervals and points have no order. You have a *set* of intervals (with start and end point) and a set of points. It is fine to implement sets with arrays but that is completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: -1: I decided to downvote this question for all the problems you can find in the comments to the question and the answers.

Comment: I've added a new answer, would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on your answer, we have no choice but to check each element of C against A and B. But since A and B are in ascending order, performance should be reasonable:

```
    int len = A.length;
    boolean[] eliminated = new boolean[len]; // initially all elements are false
    int totalEliminated = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        int c = C[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < len && A[j] <= c; j++) {
            if (B[j] >= c && !eliminated[j]) {
                System.out.println(c + " eliminates " + A[j] + " - " + B[j]);
                eliminated[j] = true;
                if (++totalEliminated == len) {
                    return i+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Added return 0 which signifies that we've gone through all elements of C but haven't managed to eliminate all the A/B ranges

Comment: The first (inner) loop could probably be made much faster by converting to a binary search, I might do that now...

Comment: Apologies, my first attempt was plain wrong. I've fixed the code now. Performance seems ok even without a binary search. I'm sure there's something clever you can do with a hashtable etc. but try it and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

If the input ranges are already ordered from smallest to largest (B[i] <= A[i+1]):

```
int bottomRangeIndex = 0;
int topRangeIndex = numberOfABRangesYouHave - 1;
int answerCounter = 0;

C.sort(); // Sort C so that it goes from smallest to largest number.

for number in C: {
    if (number < A[bottomRangeIndex]) {
        continue;
    } else if (number > B[topRangeIndex]) {
        return answerCounter;
    } else {
        while ((number > B[bottomRangeIndex++]) && (bottomRangeIndex <= topRangeIndex)) {
            // Just keeps incrementing bottomRangeIndex.
        }
        if (bottomRangeIndex > topRangeIndex) {
            return answerCounter;
        } else {
            answerCounter++;
            bottomRangeIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

This might have some bug that I am not thinking of, but basically what this does is:

1. Sorts C. I know you say you can't do this, but I fail to see why unless it's a homework problem.
2. Skips checking anything in the A,B ranges if the number from C falls completely outside of those ranges. If the current number is greater than the biggest number in the A,B ranges (B[topRangeIndex]), return the current answer counter because no further element from C (sorted) could be in the A,B ranges again.
3. Since C is sorted and the current number is greater than the bottom element in all A,B ranges, starts checking if the number in C falls inside the B end of each A range. The number being checked is always the smallest element in C, so if it fails to fall within the B end of an A range, that A,B range should never be checked again so the bottomRangeIndex is incremented.
4. If every range has been eliminated by the while loop, we are done checking (the current element in C is greater than the biggest number in any A,B range, we do not need to check anything else.
5. If the number in C being checked was NOT greater than a number at the end of an A,B range (located at bottomRangeIndex), that A,B range contained an element from C. We increment the answer counter, move the bottomRangeIndex up, and continue.

Try this and see if it works. If this is homework and you really can't sort C, then you can modify this to give you the right answer with a small amount of tweaking, but I won't say how...

Comment: Your presumption `B[i] <= A[i+1]` does not hold. It's explicit in the OP that the intervals may be overlapping.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that, I missed the A[3] when I read through and assumed that the ranges wouldn't overlap. That said, the OP is being really confusing and vague so I probably won't try to refine this unless the OP can explain the problem more clearly (like why C 'can't be sorted'). I think based on the OP's other questions that they just want us to do their homework, anyway. :P - Hopefully my answer helps someone with a similar problem, as if my assumption HAD been true, I think this would be a fairly solid algorithm for this purpose.

Comment: True, question should have been refined instead only some comments commented again...

Answer (score 1):

This is a more efficient version using ArrayLists:

```
        int len = arrA.length;
        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>(len);
        ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>(len);
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            A.add(arrA[i]);
            B.add(arrB[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            int c = C[i];
            int j = 0;
            while (j<A.size() && A.get(j) <= c) {
                if (B.get(j) >= c) {
                    A.remove(j);
                    if (A.isEmpty()) return i+1;
                    B.remove(j);
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: I don't think quadratic is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick sketch for solving it in O(n log n). It may be not the best approach in practice, but is just meant to offer an n log n approach.

To summarize, it's a sweeping line technique. Or rather sweeping point, in this case.

```
1. Sort arrays A, B, and C (cost: n log n). Think of the arrays as queues
   (that is, "remove" elements from the left by increasing a start index).
2. Create current-intervals set (initially empty. Has O(log n) operations.)
2. While A not empty or B not empty or C not empty:
3.   get the lowest element from the first (if any) elements in A, B, and C.
4.   if it's an A:
5.     Add the corresponding interval to the current-intervals list
6.   else if it's a B:
7.      Remove the corresponding interval from the current-intervals list
8.   else it must be a C, so:
9.      The answer to the query corresponding to C is the current-intervals list
        (in the current state)
```

Comment: OMG they did it again. -1. Why? This is really putting me off. I'm confident enough to say this was not a bad answer.

Comment: As I said, if you sort C then you're not providing the correct answer

Comment: @Constantinos: No need to downvote here if this was you. OP was not really clear about this. The other answers aren't downvoted neither. My answer gives an actually *efficient* solution to the problem itself as specified in the OP (as opposed to in a very unclear way half-way down the huge list of comments).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =0 ;i<C.length;i++)
for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++)
{
    if(A[i]<=C[i] && B[i]>=C[i])
   {   answer++;
       A[i] = Integer.Max_Value;
     }
}
```

It will
 give you a right answer

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with some tree structures but eventually I went back to a simple binary search, so this is now O(nlogn):

```
static int getAnswerV2a(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
    int len = A.length;
    ArrayList<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>(len);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(A[i], B[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        int c = C[i];
        binarySearch(intervals, 0, intervals.size(), c);
        if (intervals.isEmpty()) return i+1;
    }
    return -1;
}

static class Interval {
    int start, end;

    Interval(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    boolean matches(int c) {
        return start <= c && c <= end;
    }
}

// Find an interval (between indices i and j) that matches c
// When found, remove it from the List and adjust indices accordingly
static void binarySearch(ArrayList<Interval> intervals, int i, int j, int c) {
    if (i==j)
        return;
    else if (i+1==j) {
        if (intervals.get(i).matches(c))
            intervals.remove(i);
    }
    else {
        int mid = (int) Math.floor((i+j) / 2);
        Interval interval = intervals.get(mid);
        if (interval.start > c)
            binarySearch(intervals, i, mid, c);
        else if (interval.end < c)
            binarySearch(intervals, mid+1, j, c);
        else {
            intervals.remove(mid);
            binarySearch(intervals, i, j-1, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I have assumed that the intervals are sorted by ascending order in both A and B i.e. `if A[i]==A[i+1] then B[i]<B[i+1]`. If that's not the case, then it would just need some (fairly simple) code to sort the B-values.